# How to read a file from directory in phone gap?

Tags: cordova

Can you please tell me how to read the text file from a directory? I need to read a file from a folder in phone gap. I am able to save (Write). But problem is to read a file?
Can you please tell me how to read a file ?

I am able to save the file. What I need is to read the file

Code is below

```js
function readRtfFile(){
 try {
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
               function(fileSystem) {
                   fileSystem.root.getDirectory(CASENAME, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(directoryEntry) {
                       console.log("log folder is created");
                       directoryEntry.getFile(DOCUMENT_NAME+".rtf", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
                           fileEntry.createReader(function(writer) {
                               writer.readEntries(writer.length);


                           }, fail);
                       }, fail);
                   }, fail);
               },
               fail);
       }
       catch(e) {
           fail(e+"fail");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - Go to that Directory and give FileName -

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DIR_PATH, 
    function(directoryEntry) {
        console.log('Directory Entry Log - ', directoryEntry);
        directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false },

            function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(

                    function(file){
                        console.log('File Object Retrieved is - ', file);
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log('File Content - ', reader.result);
                            if(evt.target.result) {
                                console.log('Result Event - ', evt);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Error. - ', evt);
                            }
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log('File Read cannot complete on File System - ', error);
                    }
                );
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Reader cannot read from the File System - ', error);
            }
        );
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Error - ', error);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example from PhoneGap

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader

```
function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        console.log(entries[i].name);
    }
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
}

// Get a directory reader
var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

// Get a list of all the entries in the directory
directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
```

Comment: I just want to rad file which i save..?

Comment: i can't understand ? can you please elaborate dirEntry